# Why is my CSS not taken into account with the EncoreBundle webpack on Symfony?

Tags: css, symfony, webpack-encore

I started a new project on Symfony and i installed the webpack Encore using the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html). I followed this step by step, but for some reason, the CSS i write to test isn't taken into account. I've seen several similar questions on forums, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Here is what i have so far :

webpack.config.js

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or sub-directory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')

    // enables the Symfony UX Stimulus bridge (used in assets/bootstrap.js)
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    .configureBabel((config) => {
        config.plugins.push('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
    })

    // enables @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = 3;
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    //.enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you use React
    //.enableReactPreset()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

assets\app.js

```
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */

// any CSS you import will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
import './styles/app.css';

// start the Stimulus application
import './bootstrap';
```

build\app.js

```
(self["webpackChunk"] = self["webpackChunk"] || []).push([["app"],{

/***/ "./assets/controllers sync recursive ./node_modules/@symfony/stimulus-bridge/lazy-controller-loader.js! \\.[jt]sx?$":
/*!****************************************************************************************************************!*\
  !*** ./assets/controllers/ sync ./node_modules/@symfony/stimulus-bridge/lazy-controller-loader.js! \.[jt]sx?$ ***!
  \****************************************************************************************************************/
/***/ ((module, __unused_webpack_exports, __webpack_require__) => {

var map = {
    "./hello_controller.js": "./node_modules/@symfony/stimulus-bridge/lazy-controller-loader.js!./assets/controllers/hello_controller.js"
};


function webpackContext(req) {
    var id = webpackContextResolve(req);
    return __webpack_require__(id);
}
function webpackContextResolve(req) {
    if(!__webpack_require__.o(map, req)) {
        var e = new Error("Cannot find module '" + req + "'");
        e.code = 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
        throw e;
    }
    return map[req];
}
webpackContext.keys = function webpackContextKeys() {
    return Object.keys(map);
};
webpackContext.resolve = webpackContextResolve;
module.exports = webpackContext;
webpackContext.id = "./assets/controllers sync recursive ./node_modules/@symfony/stimulus-bridge/lazy-controller-loader.js! \\.[jt]sx?$";

/***/ }),

/***/ "./node_modules/@symfony/stimulus-bridge/dist/webpack/loader.js!./assets/controllers.json":
/*!************************************************************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/@symfony/stimulus-bridge/dist/webpack/loader.js!./assets/controllers.json ***!
  \************************************************************************************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "default": () => (__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__)
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony default export */ const __WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__ = ({
});

/***/ }),

/***/ "./node_modules/@symfony/stimulus-bridge/lazy-controller-loader.js!./assets/controllers/hello_controller.js":
/*!******************************************************************************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/@symfony/stimulus-bridge/lazy-controller-loader.js!./assets/controllers/hello_controller.js ***!
  \******************************************************************************************************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "default": () => (/* binding */ _default)
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_object_set_prototype_of_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.object.set-prototype-of.js */ "./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.object.set-prototype-of.js");
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_object_set_prototype_of_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_es_object_set_prototype_of_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__);
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_function_bind_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.function.bind.js */ "./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.function.bind.js");
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_function_bind_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_es_function_bind_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__);
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_object_get_prototype_of_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ = __webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.object.get-prototype-of.js */ "./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.object.get-prototype-of.js");
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_object_get_prototype_of_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_es_object_get_prototype_of_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__);
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_object_to_string_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ = __webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.object.to-string.js */ "./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.object.to-string.js");
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_object_to_string_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_es_object_to_string_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__);
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_reflect_construct_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__ = __webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.reflect.construct.js */ "./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.reflect.construct.js");
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_reflect_construct_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_es_reflect_construct_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__);
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_object_create_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__ = __webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.object.create.js */ "./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.object.create.js");
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_object_create_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_es_object_create_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__);
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_object_define_property_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__ = __webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.object.define-property.js */ "./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.object.define-property.js");
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_object_define_property_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_es_object_define_property_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__);
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_symbol_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__ = __webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.symbol.js */ "./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.symbol.js");
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_symbol_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_es_symbol_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__);
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_symbol_description_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__ = __webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.symbol.description.js */ "./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.symbol.description.js");
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_symbol_description_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_es_symbol_description_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8__);
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_symbol_iterator_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__ = __webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.symbol.iterator.js */ "./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.symbol.iterator.js");
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_symbol_iterator_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_es_symbol_iterator_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__);
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_array_iterator_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__ = __webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.array.iterator.js */ "./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.array.iterator.js");
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_array_iterator_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_es_array_iterator_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10__);
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_string_iterator_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11__ = __webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.string.iterator.js */ "./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.string.iterator.js");
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_es_string_iterator_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_es_string_iterator_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11__);
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_web_dom_collections_iterator_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12__ = __webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator.js */ "./node_modules/core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator.js");
/* harmony import */ var core_js_modules_web_dom_collections_iterator_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12___default = /*#__PURE__*/__webpack_require__.n(core_js_modules_web_dom_collections_iterator_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_12__);
/* harmony import */ var _hotwired_stimulus__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @hotwired/stimulus */ "./node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus/dist/stimulus.js");
function _typeof(obj) { "@babel/helpers - typeof"; return _typeof = "function" == typeof Symbol && "symbol" == typeof Symbol.iterator ? function (obj) { return typeof obj; } : function (obj) { return obj && "function" == typeof Symbol && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; }, _typeof(obj); }















function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } }

function _createClass(Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) _defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) _defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); Object.defineProperty(Constructor, "prototype", { writable: false }); return Constructor; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) { if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) { throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function"); } subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, { constructor: { value: subClass, writable: true, configurable: true } }); Object.defineProperty(subClass, "prototype", { writable: false }); if (superClass) _setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass); }

function _setPrototypeOf(o, p) { _setPrototypeOf = Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf.bind() : function _setPrototypeOf(o, p) { o.__proto__ = p; return o; }; return _setPrototypeOf(o, p); }

function _createSuper(Derived) { var hasNativeReflectConstruct = _isNativeReflectConstruct(); return function _createSuperInternal() { var Super = _getPrototypeOf(Derived), result; if (hasNativeReflectConstruct) { var NewTarget = _getPrototypeOf(this).constructor; result = Reflect.construct(Super, arguments, NewTarget); } else { result = Super.apply(this, arguments); } return _possibleConstructorReturn(this, result); }; }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (call && (_typeof(call) === "object" || typeof call === "function")) { return call; } else if (call !== void 0) { throw new TypeError("Derived constructors may only return object or undefined"); } return _assertThisInitialized(self); }

function _assertThisInitialized(self) { if (self === void 0) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return self; }

function _isNativeReflectConstruct() { if (typeof Reflect === "undefined" || !Reflect.construct) return false; if (Reflect.construct.sham) return false; if (typeof Proxy === "function") return true; try { Boolean.prototype.valueOf.call(Reflect.construct(Boolean, [], function () {})); return true; } catch (e) { return false; } }

function _getPrototypeOf(o) { _getPrototypeOf = Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.getPrototypeOf.bind() : function _getPrototypeOf(o) { return o.__proto__ || Object.getPrototypeOf(o); }; return _getPrototypeOf(o); }


/*
 * This is an example Stimulus controller!
 *
 * Any element with a data-controller="hello" attribute will cause
 * this controller to be executed. The name "hello" comes from the filename:
 * hello_controller.js -> "hello"
 *
 * Delete this file or adapt it for your use!
 */

var _default = /*#__PURE__*/function (_Controller) {
  _inherits(_default, _Controller);

  var _super = _createSuper(_default);

  function _default() {
    _classCallCheck(this, _default);

    return _super.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  _createClass(_default, [{
    key: "connect",
    value: function connect() {
      this.element.textContent = 'Hello Stimulus! Edit me in assets/controllers/hello_controller.js';
    }
  }]);

  return _default;
}(_hotwired_stimulus__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__.Controller);



/***/ }),

/***/ "./assets/app.js":
/*!***********************!*\
  !*** ./assets/app.js ***!
  \***********************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var _styles_app_css__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./styles/app.css */ "./assets/styles/app.css");
/* harmony import */ var _bootstrap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__ = __webpack_require__(/*! ./bootstrap */ "./assets/bootstrap.js");
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * We recommend including the built version of this JavaScript file
 * (and its CSS file) in your base layout (base.html.twig).
 */
// any CSS you import will output into a single css file (app.css in this case)
 // start the Stimulus application



/***/ }),

/***/ "./assets/bootstrap.js":
/*!*****************************!*\
  !*** ./assets/bootstrap.js ***!
  \*****************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, {
/* harmony export */   "app": () => (/* binding */ app)
/* harmony export */ });
/* harmony import */ var _symfony_stimulus_bridge__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(/*! @symfony/stimulus-bridge */ "./node_modules/@symfony/stimulus-bridge/dist/index.js");
 // Registers Stimulus controllers from controllers.json and in the controllers/ directory

var app = (0,_symfony_stimulus_bridge__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.startStimulusApp)(__webpack_require__("./assets/controllers sync recursive ./node_modules/@symfony/stimulus-bridge/lazy-controller-loader.js! \\.[jt]sx?$")); // register any custom, 3rd party controllers here
// app.register('some_controller_name', SomeImportedController);

/***/ }),

/***/ "./assets/styles/app.css":
/*!*******************************!*\
  !*** ./assets/styles/app.css ***!
  \*******************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) => {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
// extracted by mini-css-extract-plugin


/***/ })

},
/******/ __webpack_require__ => { // webpackRuntimeModules
/******/ var __webpack_exec__ = (moduleId) => (__webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = moduleId))
/******/ __webpack_require__.O(0, ["vendors-node_modules_symfony_stimulus-bridge_dist_index_js-node_modules_core-js_modules_es_fu-23ca09"], () => (__webpack_exec__("./assets/app.js")));
/******/ var __webpack_exports__ = __webpack_require__.O();
/******/ }
]);
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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
```

And the base.html.twig where the files are included :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22 viewBox=%220 0 128 128%22><text y=%221.2em%22 font-size=%2296%22>⚫️</text></svg>">
        {# Run `composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle` to start using Symfony UX #}
        {% block stylesheets %}
            {{ encore_entry_link_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}

        {% block javascripts %}
            {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <p>Header</p>
        </header>

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}

        <footer>
            <p>Footer</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

My css file is only here for testing, so it's juste a color modification of `<h1>` and `<p>`

Up till now, all the answers i found were things that are apparently correct in my files. Does anyone have an idea on what's wrong ?
(i also tried to use the classic `<link rel=stylesheet href="...">` instead of the encorer_entry_*, but it didn't work either)

Comment: did you build it? did you cleard browser cache?

Comment: Yeah, i used the yarn watch command and i cleared the cache, but it didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved ! I actually had an issue with the path leading to the css file (the setOutputPath in the webpack.config.js was not adapted to my config)

Comment: Great comment although not enough information for an answer, please add more details, formatting, what you set for setOutputPath etc.